# is there any difference in validation of validates_uniqueness_of and uniqueness?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name ,presence: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name ,presence: true,uniqueness: true
end
```

is there any difference in validation of the given two models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to accurately answer this question:

1 - It behaves in exactly the same way.

In this sense, there's no difference. `validates_uniqueness_of` generates exactly the same validation as the `:uniqueness` flag on `validates`.

2 - There are reasons to do it with the flags

In terms of reading the models, the flags help because they allow you to put all the validations on an attribute (here, it's name) in the same place. So when you rad down, you see validations on name and you can be confident you know what they all are on that line.

It's also worth noting that the flags are a newer style and it's probable the older, more wordy style, will be removed from Rails at some point in the future.